# How to get 2560x1440 resolution on ext monitor from MacBook Pro 15" early 2008?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

My old MacBook Pro 15" early 2008 is said to [support up to 2560x1600](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP4?locale=en_US) resolution on an external display. There's a dual-link DVI output (25 pins), NVidia GeForce 8600M GT 256Mb, 4Gb RAM, 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Monitor (27" 2560x1440) has HDMI and DisplayPort inputs.

I tried various DVI-to-HDMI adaptors with a proven good HDMI-HDMI cable. Latter used with my newer M1 MacBook Pro with the same monitor at 2560x1440 resoluion: sharp and perfect.

The problem with the 2008 MBP is the displayed image. It looks like its missing some of the pixels.
[image: photo of the display problem]

"Displays" system preference shows that the external monitor is working at native 2560x1440 resolution.

Is it that all DVI-to-HDMI adapters I have tried were bad? Got few from a trusted store, specs claim support for the 2560x1600 @ 60Hz. In example: [image]

Or, perhaps, that resolution can't be achieved from DVI to HDMI, and I should be looking for a monitor with a dual link DVI input?

Comment: Your Mac has “dual” DVI outputs?  I remember it only having one. Those GPUs were flaky back then, you may be dealing with bad hardware. Do you have access to another monitor to test with just to see if the GOU is working properly?

Comment: @Allan, single socket. As I have read, DVI has various "flavors": single-, dual- mode DVI-D (digital), analog DVI-i. It is the pins used that define. The 25 pin layout on the photo matches the dual-DVI mode, the only capable of resolutions higher than 1920x1080.
I don't have another 2560 monitor to test at the moment. The monitor, I assume, is fine: two other, newer MacBook Pros, have no issues with it over DisplayPort and HDMI, too.
The GPU on the early 2008 MBP should be okay, too: I used to do 3D/motion graphics back in the day on it. Driving external monitor at 1920x1080 has no issues.

Comment: Ahhh..i know what you mean now.  It’s “Dual Link DVI”..  This was a very special DVI and the cables and adapters were super rare and expensive.  What’s happening is the DVI to HDMI converter is only sending half the signal to the monitor. You need one that supports dual link and they aren’t manufactured anymore. You’ll have to scour ebay for somethibg like that.

Comment: @Allan, I've tried reading DVI standard specs. As I understand, the 2560x1600 @ 30 Hz is the top possible throughput for a single-link DVI. And same res @ 60Hz refresh rate is the starting point for a dual-link DVI. The specs for a cheap ($8 Chinese DEXP brand) DVI to HDMI adapter says "2560x1600 @ 60 Hz", which lets assume the dual-link DVI. Unless the stated capability is faulty : )

Comment: Your confusing capability and configuration.  Just because one link can deliver a specific resolution and frame rate, doesn’t mean that the signals used to create that resolution/frame rate are delivered the same way on two different DVI adapters.  Dual link had more bandwidth for better quality .  That doesn’t mean it was single link for the lower quality resolutions.